# Hazelcast Management Center not showing Maps/MultiMaps

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Not seeing the Map/MultiMap data on the Hazelcast Management Center.  My environment consists of:

- Remote Hazelcast: 3.7.2
- Hazelcast Management Console: 3.7.2
- Hazelcast client: 3.7.2

I am using Hazelcast Maps indirectly using `quartz` and the [quartz-scheduler-hazelcast-jobstore](https://github.com/FlavioF/quartz-scheduler-hazelcast-jobstore). I created one trigger so there is some information that is added to the Maps.

I have verified that the connection is made to remote hazelcast its connection to the management console, as I can see the Members tab populated, as well as the Topics tab from other data in my app.

Any ideas as to why the maps are not shown?

Not a lot of logging happening, but this is what the client shows:

> 2018-02-02T15:55:23.745-0500 |   |  INFO | RMI TCP
>   Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 | com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService |
>   XMHZClient [dev] [3.7.2] HazelcastClient 3.7.2 (20161004 - 540b01c) is
>   STARTING 2018-02-02T15:55:24.29-0500 |   |  INFO | RMI TCP
>   Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 | com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService |
>   XMHZClient [dev] [3.7.2] HazelcastClient 3.7.2 (20161004 - 540b01c) is
>   STARTED 2018-02-02T15:55:24.130-0500 |   |  INFO | XMHZClient.event-3
>   | com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientMembershipListener | XMHZClient
>   [dev] [3.7.2]
>
> Members [1](https://github.com/FlavioF/quartz-scheduler-hazelcast-jobstore) {     Member [172.17.0.3]:5701 -
>   b79ad451-02f2-43d4-8b66-ca91fbd677e1 }
>
> 2018-02-02T15:55:24.132-0500 |   |  INFO | XMHZClient.user-1 |
>   com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService | XMHZClient [dev] [3.7.2]
>   HazelcastClient 3.7.2 (20161004 - 540b01c) is CLIENT_CONNECTED

Comment: Can you list the maps from Management Center console?

Comment: Can you confirm that you don't see the maps even though the trigger is run? Also, do you not see quartz-scheduler-hazelcast-jobstore's internal maps (such as `job-store-map-job`) or your own maps that you used in your jobs? If it is your own maps, can you please share your job class implementation?

Comment: @ozan-kılıç I am not able to list any of the maps.

Comment: @alparslan-avci Yes, I have a trigger running every minute, another every 5 minutes.  None of the quartz-scheduler-hazelcast-jobstore's internal maps are seen on the console.

Comment: Can you please share the logs of Hazelcast client?

Comment: See logs added above.

Comment: @PhilipWiebe can you see any other distributed object in the ManCenter, other than the members? Also, can you see any error in member log regarding ManCenter?

Comment: Yes, I see a lot of Topics that we create for messaging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@PhilipWiebe, since you see a lot of topics in ManCenter, I believe you're hitting the limit of reported objects. By default, each Hazelcast node only reports 100 object statistics. You need to set `hazelcast.mc.max.visible.instance.count` parameter on each Hazelcast node to a value greater than your total dist. objects count. This behavior is changing in upcoming 3.9.3 release.

Comment: Thank you!  It worked!  I now see all the maps/multimaps!